# Partition algorithm to split set of objects

Tags: algorithm

Can somebody confirm if an algorithm exist to solve this? I assume even if something exist, it will be NP complete.

Lets say there is a `Set<Set<Object>>` where the total number of elements is 165. This has to be partitioned into three sets of each 55 elements(or lesser), such that elements in the inner set is not distributed among multiple sets after partition.

Please don't ditch this question as homework types. I have searched enough and I couldn't classify this algorithm properly for me to research efficiently.

Comment: `such that elements in the inner set is not distributed among multiple sets after partition` - this part is not clear,you mean each set needs to have a unique element...?

Comment: Could you provide an example?

Comment: The input is a set of set of objects. The expected output is three different set of objects in such a way that all objects in inner set(in the input) go into the same set(one of the three output sets) and also the number of objects in each set doesn't exceed 55 (or any input input)

Comment: You're partitioning the outer set, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this exists and it is NP-hard.  It is the bin-packing problem with the size of the bins being 55 and the size of the objects being the sizes of the inner sets.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem for more.

Comment: If I understand the problem correctly, this is not equivalent to the bin-packing problem, and in fact can be solved in polynomial time.